# Composer cannot install dependencies when deploying an app on Heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I have been trying without success to deploy my app on Heroku. I get the error below:

> Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
>    !     WARNING: A post-autoload-dump script terminated with an error
>    !     ERROR: Dependency installation failed!
>    !
>    !     The 'composer install' process failed with an error. The cause
>    !     may be the download or installation of packages, or a pre- or
>    !     post-install hook (e.g. a 'post-install-cmd' item in 'scripts')
>    !     in your 'composer.json'

Comment: Any luck finding a solution?

Comment: @RiggsFolly no luck so far.

Comment: yea, I had to re-install my composer